# How to send a multiple emails at a time in cakephp

Tags: email, cakephp, cakephp-1.3, cakephp-1.2, bulk

I need to send multiple emails at a time, can any one have example? or any idea ?
I need to send mail to all my site users at a time (Mail content is same for all)

Currently i using following code in a for loop

```
        $this->Email->from     = '<no-reply@noreply.com>';
        $this->Email->to       =  $email;
        $this->Email->subject  =   $subject ;
        $this->Email->sendAs   = 'html';
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Cakephp 2.0 I used the following code:

```
$result = $email->template($template, 'default')
    ->emailFormat('html')
    ->to(array('first@gmail.com', 'second@gmail.com', 'third@gmail.com')))
    ->from($from_email)
    ->subject($subject)
    ->viewVars($data);
```

Comment: '->to()' with an array of email addresses works, but it should be noted that the email will send them as a list of addresses in the 'to' field - not as individual emails as one might be expecting. Consider using '->bcc()' just in case you don't want to send every user on your site the email address of every user on your site.

Comment: Its static way not dynamic to emails.

Comment: @IndrajeetSingh I given example.. incase of that  static array you can pass your dynamic array.. These are very basic. Exactly what you want ? Because I fetched thousands of users from DB directly using Cakephp LIST query and passing to that TO Parameter.. The way you are doing is foreach so thats not the proper way.. I told based on my work exp.. But u down voted my answer .. ha ha ha

Answer (score 12):

I think you have 2 possibilities:

**foreach**

Let's assume you have a function `mail_users` within your `UsersController`

```
function mail_users($subject = 'Sample subject') {
    $users = $this->User->find('all', array('fields' => array('email'));
    foreach ($users as $user) {
        $this->Email->reset();
        $this->Email->from     = '<no-reply@noreply.com>';
        $this->Email->to       =  $user['email'];
        $this->Email->subject  =  $subject ;
        $this->Email->sendAs   = 'html';
        $this->Email->send('Your message body');
    }
}
```

In this function the `$this->Email->reset()` is important.

**using BCC**

```
function mail_users($subject = 'Sample subject') {
    $users = $this->User->find('all', array('fields' => array('email'));
    $bcc = '';
    foreach ($users as $user) {
        $bcc .= $user['email'].',';
    }
    $this->Email->from     = '<no-reply@noreply.com>';
    $this->Email->bcc      = $bcc;
    $this->Email->subject  = $subject;
    $this->Email->sendAs   = 'html';
    $this->Email->send('Your message body');
}
```

Now you can just call this method with a link to `/users/mail_users/subject`

For more information be sure to read the manual on the [Email Component](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1283/Email).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$tests = array();
foreach($users as $user) {
    $tests[] = $user['User']['email'];
}

$mail = new CakeEmail();
$mail->to($tests) 
    ->from('<no-reply@noreply.com>')
    ->subject('ALERT')
    ->emailFormat('html')
    ->send('Your message here');
```

Comment: Its not a standard way.. using foreach

Comment: Can you explain standard way?

Comment: Don't use foreach.. If you have 100000 users then its not the right format. Take the users email id and pass in To field