# Email Function (replyBCC) in cakePHP

Tags: cakephp

is there a function in cakePHP than can set BCC when user reply to a email?

it like a function repltTo but i want to set the BCC not the TO?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Very highly doubt this is possible with ANY system.

Comment: Are you using Mailer Component of Cake?

Comment: Check This http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19261796/how-to-send-email-for-all-users-with-cakephp

Answer (score 0):

[See](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/email.html#configuration). There's a function `CakeEmail::replyTo()`

Comment: I don't think this answers his question.  It sounds like he wants to be able to auto-fill in the BCC field on a user's REPLY to his email.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is not a way to auto fill-in the BCC field on user's reply unless you're actually having them "reply" through your system.  (But if that was the case, I doubt you'd be asking here, as it's very well documented how to add a "BCC" to an email).